# Defining actions for SimpleForm and rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I'm getting this odd error, as if SimpleForm isn't even installed:

```
undefined method `simple_form_for'
```

SimpleForm IS in my gemfile and I've installed:

```
Using simple_form (2.0.2)
```

I'm running on the Pow server, so it's restarting every time.

```
#events_controller.rb
class admin::EventsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @event = Event.new
  end

#Event.rb
class Event
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :summary
  field :start_date
  field :end_date
end

#new.html.haml
= simple_form_for [:admin, @event] do |f|
  = f.input :summary
  = f.input :start_date
  = f.input :end_date
```

Any ideas why it seems like SimpleForm isn't even installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you run the generator after you installed the gem? In your console you need to run this:

```
rails generate simple_form:install
```

Comment: If you look at the gem documentation, simple_form depends on Active Record. For instance here, https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/blob/master/lib/simple_form/action_view_extensions/form_helper.rb. Maybe try something else if you are using Mongoid.

Comment: yeah you're definitely right, but I don't know if that's the actual problem here, because I think the basic functionality still works between the two. Anyway, I somehow got this to work, and I don't know how. All of these files look exactly the same. I was switching between another branch making scaffolds trying to get back to the basics, and when I switched back to this branch it just worked. Maybe some random config somewhere was screwing things up? At least I didn't pull _all_ my hair out.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the command:
rails generate simple_form:install

And - it didn't run. Instead the output looked like I gave rails an ill-formed command line and it gave back a copy of the usage file.

Then, within RubyMine, I tried it again - this time got an error traceback - first line is shown below:

```
/home/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/generators/base.rb:265:in `const_defined?': wrong constant name SimpleForm:installGenerator
```

After commenting out the lines 265-269 in base.rb:

```
#  if last && last.const_defined?(last_name.camelize, false)
#     raise Error, "The name '#{class_name}' is either already used in your application " <<
#            "or reserved by Ruby on Rails. Please choose an alternative and run "  <<
#            "this generator again."
#  end
```

and running the command again, I got:

```
/home/user1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby -e $stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift) /home/user1/RubymineProjects/TravelAid/bin/rails generate generator simple_form:install -s
      create  lib/generators/simple_form:install
      create  lib/generators/simple_form:install/simple_form:install_generator.rb
      create  lib/generators/simple_form:install/USAGE
      create  lib/generators/simple_form:install/templates

Process finished with exit code 0
```

This looks pretty good, but I haven't gone back to check if simple_form works yet.

Under lib/generators, I have:

```
simple_form
  templates
  simple_form_generator.rb
  USAGE
simple_form.install
  templates
  simple_form.install_generator.rb  (created about 18 minutes ago - consistent with new)
  USAGE
```

I am running Rails 4.0.0 and ruby-2.0.0-p247 within Rubymine